# .jar garbled output on web browser when downloaded

Tags: deployment, java-me, midlet

I deployed my .jar file to the web server and attempted to download the .jar file using the old Nokia phone via its web browser. Upon finishing downloading, a garbled output is displayed on the web browser instead of prompting for installation. What went wrong? Do I have to create some sort of installation file for my .jar application? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MIDlet is a combination of a `jad` and `jar` file.  While some browsers permit direct installation of the jar, one would usually point a browser to the `jad` to install.

And ensure the MIME types are set correctly.

`jad`s need a MIME type of `text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor`, and `jar`s are `application/java-archive`.

Comment: The problem was indeed due to MIME type for .jar and .jad. Thanks!